# In regular language inference, how is the observation table kept consistent?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

I am trying to understand the background literature on regular language inference in the TTT paper ("The TTT Algorithm: A Redundancy-Free Approach to Active Automata Learning" by Isberner, Howar and Steffen). In it, they say in *Related Work*, "Maler and Pnueli[22] suggested adding all suffixes of the counter examples to the table."

When looking at [22] "On the Learnability of Infinitary Regular Sets." by Maler and Pnueli, I see that they say this on page 18 footnote: "In fact, Angluin uses an additional notation of a consistent table but this can be eliminated by a slight modification to L*: instead of adding the prefixes of a counter-example to S, add their suffixes to E. This way, the table is always consistent."

I have gone through Angluin's "Learning Regular Sets from Queries and Counter Examples" where she defines L*, and the way consistent tables are defined says that "An observation table is called consistent provided whenever s1 and s2 are elements of S such that row(s1) = row(s2) for all a in A, row(s1.a) = row(s2.a)".

I do not see how Maler and Pnueli's suggestion is justified. How does adding all suffixes to E capture the consistence requirement of the observation table as defined by Angluin? (From what I can understand from Angluin's paper, the consistency property is to make sure that if two prefixes reach the same state we confirm that they are the same by checking all outgoing transitions from the state reached from both prefixes. By using all suffixes of the counter example, are they substituting another mechanism (following one suffix to its end, and making sure all intermediate states encountered from both prefixes are the same) rather than checking all transitions from the given state reached by both prefixes to ensure that the state reached by two prefixes are the same?)